# Coloring boxes of dataframe based on values in streamlit?

Tags: pandas, streamlit

I have a dataframe as such:

```py
data = {
    'Category': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Value': [25, 75, 50]
}
```

My goal is to make a dataframe/table in streamlit where `values >= 50` are green, and red otherwise.

I've tried many different things with `df.style.format`, but the table does not show up with different colors. The closest I've gotten is with this code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
styled_df = df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn').format(precision=2)
st.dataframe(styled_df)
```

But I would prefer `values >=50` green and red otherwise.

Comment: `df.style.map(lambda x: f"background-color: {'green' if x>=50 else 'red'}", subset='Value')`, see [Styler.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.map.html) for detailes

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map` from Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.map.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.map):

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Category': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Value': [25, 75, 50]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.style.map(lambda x: f"background-color: {'green' if x>=50 else 'red'}", subset='Value')
st.dataframe(df)
```

It gives:

[image]

---

If you are using Python 3.8, this method is not available. Either use Python >= 3.9 or use the `applymap` method instead.